# Edit and Continue generating phantom errors

Tags: c++, debugging, mfc, visual-studio-2013, edit-and-continue

I am attempting to debug a program in vs2013 using edit and continue.  I compile and run the program, hit enter to add a new line, then choose apply code changes.  When it attempts to compile using edit and continue, i get the prompt saying that edits were made which cannot be compiled.  To be clear, i did nothing to add a new line.
Here are the vitals:
VS2013 IDE running program written in vs2010 and is compiling with the vs2010 compiler set in project settings.
Version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1
C++/MFC
Win32

Eanble Edit and Continue - Check
Native-Only
   Enable native Edit and Continue - Check
   Invoked by debug commands - check
   Ask first  - check
Warn about stale code - check
Relink code changes after debugging - Check
Allow precompiling - check
Enable while debugging an app running under other user account - NOT CHECKED.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try upgrading the Platform Toolset (I would guess from v100 to v120)?
If that fails, can you give me more details?
- does this happen for every project or a particular one?
- what is the full message you are getting?
- are there any errors/warnings in Error List and Output windows?
- is the right debug engine used? (you can verify this by looking in the Output window:
with native EnC enabled: 'MSTest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Temp\MSTest\Debug\MSTest.exe', Symbols loaded.
without: 'MSTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Temp\MSTest\Debug\MSTest.exe'. Symbols loaded.

Comment: -At this time, we can't change the toolset.  We are dependent on the v100 at the moment.  
-The full message i get is: Edits were made which cannot be compiled.
then i am given edit/stop/ignore.  I've seen it plenty of times when there is actually an error present.
-There are no errors/warnings displayed
-'MyProj.exe': Loaded 'C:\MyProgs\MyProj.exe', Symbols loaded.

I haven't tried this with our other programs.  I loaded up vs2010 and it worked with no problem.